# Retrieve data from several tables in SQL server database to Treeview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I retrieve data from several tables in sql server database & show them in hierarchical at treeveiw in windows application, example for what I want to do is that:

I have 4 tables in my database, they are:

---

```
**Country table**
-----------------
CountryID  CountryName
1               USA
2               England
3               France

**City table**
---------------
CityID     CityName      CountryID
1          New York         1
2          Los Anglos       1
3          London           2

**Customers table**
-------------------
CustomerID   CustomerName    Address             CityID
1            Eric             wall street          1
2            Beth             london street        3

**SubCustomers**
----------------
SubCustomerID      SubCustomerName     CustomerID
1                  Jason                     1
2                  Scott                     1
```

And I want to show my data in treeview like that:

```
--USA                  **-----> Parent Node**
----New York           -----> first child node
------Eric             -----> second child node
--------Jason          -----> third child node
--------Scott          -----> third child node
----Los Anglos         -----> first child node
--England              -----> Parent Node
----London             -----> first child node
------Beth             -----> second child node
```

Can anyone help me please, I use Visual studio 2010 - C# - and MS-SQL Server 2008.

Comment: what did you try so far? how do you load the datatables for now?

Answer (score 0):

The best modern solution is to create a [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) application (for the GUI) and access the database using either [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx).

An example of binding database data to a list using WPF and LINQ to SQL can be found here:

[Example of DB binding](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/binding_in_linq-sql.aspx?fid=1086416&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=25)

Comment: Thanks for your replying Michael Goldshteyn, but actually I use visual studio 2010 Windows forms and ADO.NET